# do I need all 3 Nvidia Geforce Experience autoboots?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I'm using Nvidia Geforce Experience, and while checking msconfig, it says the following 3 bootups:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Nvidia Corporation\NVIDIA Update Core\nvtmru.exe
C:\Program Files(x86)\Nvidia Corporation\Update Core\NvBackend.exe
C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe C:\Windows\system32\nvspcap64.dll,ShadowPlayOnSystemStart
```

Do I need all 3 of these for Geforce Experience to work?

Comment: Go to the services.msc, and disable the services from nvidia you don't need, like shadowplay or streaming functions and 3D. But the ones you don't know about leave them be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need the first two, they are for updating the nvidia software, and i would disable them, or set to manual so they might start if you are using the nvidia control console.

I would disable shadowplay ONLY IF you run verylight-light gpu tasks. if you use any graphic software / games / video / dual screen - keep it.

Answer (score 3):

Shadowplay is just for recording. It's not needed at all